# Random order of WP_Query results with highest meta value

Tags: php, wp-query, post-meta

I need to random of cars with highest price.

My code:

```
$argsLoop = array(
    'post_type'      => 'cars',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged'          => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'cars_price', 
    'orderby' => 'cars_price',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

How to leave the result of this query random?

Comment: What do you mean by “shuffle” exactly?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Sorry for my English, I need a random result, but among the 12 cars of higher price

Comment: No reason to be sorry about. I just wanted to be sure that we understand it the same way... :) So you want the 12 card with lowest prices and then shuffle these cars so they are showed in random order, right?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Exact! : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you're almost there. Let's say you have this query:

```
$argsLoop = array(
    'post_type'      => 'cars',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged'          => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'cars_price', 
    'orderby' => 'cars_price',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$cars = new WP_Query( $argsLoop );
// All you have to add is this line:
shuffle( $cars->posts );
```

Now you can do standard loop and the selected cars will be showed in random order.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)